# Learning ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'd like to use ExtJS4 for my next project. However, I'm new to Ext and not that well versed in Javascript's finer points either.

There are a couple good books about ExtJS3 available. Should I learn from those old books first and then apply the knowledge to v4 or has the API changed so much that there is no point in learning the old one first?

If not, what's the best way to learn for an Ext newbie?

Comment: The author of ExtJs in action is working on a book for 4, but it won't be out for a while(Early next year I believe?), it's on his forum.  Right now I think the best way to learn it is using the Ext4 documentation.  However, you can get a good grasp of the library using one of the books on 3, and then use the docs to migrate your existing code.

Comment: The other thing to think about is that Ext JS 4 isn't *really* production ready at the moment; they're still ironing out a lot of bugs and pushing release candidates to Sencha devs all the time to get frequent feedback. While there are some big changes in thinking (the data and class models being some of the largest), learning the basics of Ext JS 3 is definitely not going to hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're wanting to learn ExtJS 4 **right now** then you're going to struggle for any good books on the subject because its only about 6 weeks since it was released.

There are great guides on the Sencha Website on how to migrate from ExtJS 3 -> 4 ([this one for example](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/)) which might help you along the way if you choose to tackle 3 before 4.

In my honest opinion, the quickest way to learn ExtJS is to pick an example from the [Sencha website](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) and have a play around with it.

ExtJS 3 is a lot easier to learn than ExtJS 4 in my humble opinion. I've been using ExtJS for 3 years and thought that 4 was a big switch in thinking.

Comment: That's why I'd like to avoid learning obsolete APIs.

Comment: I would agree, it's going to be more difficult for you to learn ExtJS 4, but use the sencha forums, the examples and stackoverflow.com and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

I finally completed a Tutorial series that demonstrates how to use the new MVC pattern and associations classes of ExtJS-4 with CouchDB by means of Peter Muller's software patch.  The series includes an introductory write-up, several video screencasts, and some other resources.  You can read all about it and view the screencasts here:

http://averydc.com/ee/index.php/blog/couchdb_extjs4_a_winning_combination

I probably made some mistakes and perhaps mis-spoke here and there, so please feel free to offer constructive criticism.  You can post comments on my Blog post.  My intention is to help both CouchDB users and/or ExtJS-4 users get a jump start with building an MVC client/server CRUD application using document databases as an alternative to relational databases.

Peter Muller created a software patch for ExtJS-4 and Sencha Touch that makes working with de-normalized databases much easier.  I find it is a very maintainable solution for me. If Peter's software patch is something that will work for you, please request from Sencha devs that the patch be integrated into an official release of ExtJS-4 and Sencha Touch in the future. The thread is being watched by Ed Spencer, as he is curious to see the demand.  To add your voice, get the patch, or report issues, please post a comment in Peter's thread here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127547-Sencha-Platform-denormalized-Data-patch&highlight=couch

Hope this fills a need...  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also new to Ext and decided to start with Extjs 4 (However, we use extjs 2 in our projects at work!).

Last week I finally got the book Ext JS 4 First Look by Loiane Groner and took a look at it with the hope to find it a useful resource for learning extjs and get over it. But after a bit skimming through, I found out that the book is only suitable for switchers from Extjs3 to Extjs4 and is of no help to newcomers.

IMHO, learning with playing around with examples only gives you experience but you would gain no insight(But is the fastest way as Jaitsu indicated). In order to become an expert, you need to be an experienced develper with a great insight! So my suggestion is to learn extjs 3 from a book and then read Groner's book and begin playing around with the exercises simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I bought the book directly from the Publisher: http://www.packtpub.com/ext-js-4-first-look/book

They even have an option of buying an e-book

Answer (score 1):

Apart from  ExtJS 4 first look  https://www.packtpub.com/ext-js-4-first-look/book

there are couple of more books here:

ExJS in Action Second Edition covers ExJS 4.0
http://manning.com/garcia3/

http://www.packtpub.com/sencha-ext-js-4-web-application-development-cookbook/book

Answer (score 0):

Book on extjs4 [http://www.amazon.com/Ext-JS-4-First-Look/dp/1849516669/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330388504&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849516669)